# find the difference between duplicate elements in array O(N) cordiality test

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

I have went through a cordiality test that requires me to write a function to find the max of difference between duplicate elements. 
for example if I have an array of N elements  A[I]=K where K<=N

```
A[0]=1
A[1]=6
A[2]=1
A[3]=2
A[4]=3
A[5]=6
A[6]=2
```

here is the max of the difference between duplicate elements is 4 ( 5-1=4)since

```
A[1]=A[5] the difference =5-1=4
A[0]=A[2] the difference =2-0=2
A[3]=A[6] the difference =6-3=3
```

the max is 4

so I should write a method that returns 4  but with time complexity O(N) its

the solutions came to my mind with time complexity O(N2) and O(NLogN)

Comment: Do you know the range of values for the elements ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a hash table and do a linear scan.

Store in the table the first occurrence of the element. If you see it again, calculate the difference and update the global maximum, if needed.

Note: if you know that the range of the elements is limited, you can also use an array.

Answer (score 0):

I've done something like this in the past.

Make this container:

```
int max = 0;
map<int, list<int>>
```

The idea is you iterate through the list and add a value to the map when you see it. The list contains the array index of the elements as you discover them.

Ie the map for 6 should contain 1->5. Each iteration, if the size of the list > 1, compute: `curIndex - *--list.end() -` O(1). If this value is greater than max, update max.

So O(N) to iterate the list, O(1) to check size of list and O(1) to compute new max. Max will contain the answer. O(N) complexity overall.

Comment: Whoops I thought this was a C++ question. :/

Comment: `map` is a tree, accessing an element is O(log N).